# Is this an ASP.NET Asynchronous page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I have read about ASP.NET Asynchronous Page, after reading some material I'm still a bit not clear about the concept. Therefore, I write something like this below to seek for verification that is this an Asynchronous Page? Or I have misunderstood the concept? Thanks you very much for your insights.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Async="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker bw = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

    void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Form.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p>Finished.</p>"));    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say no, that is not the way an asynchronous page is typically implemented in ASP.NET.

First, the worker process (the ASP.NET engine) uses a pool of threads to serve the requests that arrive to the server. So, you don't have to use `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker` at all in your code.

I'm not an expert on the matter, so I think it's best for you to grasp the fundamentals straight from the source. Here are 2 good blog posts in regards to asynchronous pages in ASP.NET:

- [Wicked Code - Asynchronous Pages in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx)
- [Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET 4.5](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45)